# How to update entity of D365 Finance and Operations using OData?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I want to update the ItemDetails in entity "PurchaseOderLines" via OData Rest API. First, I have verified that can able to filter the particular ItemNumber via API. I can able to filter by using the get operation.

**Get Url:**
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.operations.dynamics.com/data/PurchaseOrderHeaders?$filter=PurchaseOrderNumber eq '12345678'

However, I am trying to update the quantity of the ItemNumber using the Patch Method. Below, I have provided a URL for that. it does not work properly. Could you please help me with how to update the entity in D365 Finance & Operation?

**Post Url:**
[https://xxxxxxxxx.operations.dynamics.com/data/PurchaseOrderLinesV2(PurchaseOrderNumber='12345678',ItemNumber='99999')](https://xxxxxxxxx.operations.dynamics.com/data/PurchaseOrderLinesV2(PurchaseOrderNumber=%2712345678%27,ItemNumber=%2799999%27))

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://doc2ent.info/community/get-full-information-about-entity/

You can set the `Accept` header on your request to `application/json;odata.metadata=full` and then the you should additional properties in the response, including an `"@odata.id"` property, the value of that propertly should be the unique url that you have to send your update request to.

If `POST` doesn't work, maybe try `PUT` :)